# CSS3 animationStarted event trigger with a delay of 25/30 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, events, css

i have made a JSFiddle to show the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/yvTje/

In few words, i put some listener on the animationStart event, add a new class to the element and then, in a plugin i do, i need to check if the element have an animation (can be associated with the class) before doing, or not, something.

My probleme is i have to wait 25/80 millisecond before it's possible to check if an animation is started or not...

Something i do bad or any suggestion ?

```
var animationStarted = false,
    s = '';

var listener = function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "animationstart":
        case "webkitAnimationStart":
            // BUT "animationstart" do not trigger instantaneously
            // For the moment i compute 25 milliseconds on my Chrome & FF
            var diff = (new Date().getTime()) - s;
            console.log('animationStarted after ' + diff + ' ms'); // HERE THE RESULT : 30ms
            break;
    }
};

var setup = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("watchme");
    e.addEventListener("animationstart", listener, false);
    e.addEventListener("webkitAnimationStart", listener, false);
    // HERE WE ADD THE CLASS
    e.className = "slidein";
    s = new Date().getTime(); // Time at witch the class (with anim) is applyed
};

setup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use feature detection even before you try to start the animation.

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");

div.style["animation"] = "animName 5s infinite";
div.style["WebkitAnimation"] = "animName 5s infinite";

if (div.style["animationDuration"] == "5s") {
    // Supports animation
} else  (div.style["WebkitAnimationDuration"] == "5s") {
    // Supports -webkit-animation
}
```

This tests for the browser's ability to set individual style attributes using shorthand. If you just set a value and read it back the same way, you'll get false positives.

EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood the problem.

Regarding using events to check for stuff, you will probably have to wait a few milliseconds, no matter what you do... You could check the style definitions themselves using document.styleSheets, but that would be pretty exhausting, depending on the specificity of the css.

```
var animationName = "";
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    var rules = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;
    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; ++j) {
        var rule = rules[j];
        if (theElement.matchesSelector(rule.selectorText)) {
            var theStyle = rule.style;
            animationName = theStyle["WebkitAnimationName"];
        }
    }
}
```

It's a pretty crude way of doing this, I know...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Agree with you, for the moment i think there's only 2 solutions, check in the plain style/class if we got a duration, or check if animation started, inside a timeout of 50ms... I don't like both but nothing perfect, i will take yours and parse stylesheet at the beginning of my plugin..

Comment: After some pondering I think that the delay here is what gives you the event without the performance issues that DOM Mutation Events had.